# Django + Jinja/css vs Django + React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, django, jinja2

I'm trying to develop a simple neat website using Django with a second page that has a python application.

If you use React to cover the front end, can you avoid having to use the combination of Jinja/css?

Thanks, Sad_man